# Function Undefined when calling the dispatch method

Tags: javascript, vue.js, quasar

[the error shows : [vuex] unknown action type: tasks/fbreadData](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cnT5U.jpg)

Comment: Hi! Please copy source code here instead of posting screenshots. This can help others find your question and the solution if they have similar issues.

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Answer (score 0):

you did a minor mistake in your call.

From your picture I can gather, that you are calling the function with `dispatch('tasks/fbreadData)`, but `fbreadData({commit})` seems to be within your getters from store-tasks.js

You can either call it as a getter.

```
handleAuthChange({commit, rootGetters}) {
  // ...
  rootGetters['tasks/fbreadData'];

}
```

or you can reposition `fbreadData` into your actions in store-tasks.js.

I would decide that depending on whether you need to do additional tasks within `fbreadData`, or you are just returning a value.

Function does Something = Action

Function does nothing but return a value = Getter